# How to execute a JDBC Kafka Connector jar

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I cloned https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc, but i'm having issues understanding how to execute this.

Comment: It would be much easier to download Confluent OSS, which has these connectors included. https://www.confluent.io/download/

Answer (score 1):

`kafka-connect-jdbc` is a Kafka Connector for loading data to and from any JDBC-compatible database. The documentation for this connector can be found [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html).

**Minimal example for JDBC Source Connector (from sqlite db)**

[Download](https://www.confluent.io/download/) Confluent and start the services using `confluent start`

Create a sqlite db

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

Create a table and add some rows:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES('giorgos');
```

Load the JDBC source connector:

```
confluent load jdbc-source
```

(Your output should resemble:)

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlite:test.db",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "topic.prefix": "test-sqlite-jdbc-",
    "name": "jdbc-source"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": null
}
```

Run a console consumer in order to consume the data produced in the topic `test-sqlite-jdbc-users`:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-sqlite-jdbc-users --from-beginning
{"id":1,"name":{"string":"giorgos"}}
```

Comment: You're kinda missing that 1) Confluent needs downloaded 2) `confluent start` would need ran

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for that. Updated my answer to include them.